# How to pass Pandas dataframe columns as **kwargs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 10],
                        'B': [10, 0, 13, 10, 0, 8, 12, 13, 15, 0],
                        'C': [2, 10, 0, 0, 10, 8, 12, 13, 0, 0],
                        'D': [3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                        'E': [0, 3, 5, 10, 0, 8, 12, 13, 15, 0],
                        'F': [9, 5, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 13, 15, 0]})

def calcMoe(df, e1, m1, e2, m2, e3, m3, e4, m4):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if df[e1] == 0:
        x = max(x, df[m1])
    else:
        y = y + df[m1] ** 2
    if df[e2] == 0:
        x = max(x, df[m2])
    else:
        y = y + df[m2] ** 2
    if df[e3] == 0:
        x = max(x, df[m3])
    else:
        y = y + df[m3] ** 2
    if df[e4] == 0:
        x = max(x, df[m4])
    else:
        y = y + df[m4] ** 2

    return (x ** 2 + y)
```

**Using above dataset this code works:**

```
kwds = {'e1': 'A', 'm1': 'B', 'e2': 'C', 'm2': 'D', 'e3': 'E', 'm3': 'F', 'e4': 'D', 'm4': 'A'}
df['G'] = df.apply(calcMoe, axis=1, **kwds)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F    G
0   1  10   2   3   0   9  191
1   0   0  10   2   3   5   29
2   3  13   0   3   5   0  187
3   4  10   0   4  10  10  232
4   5   0  10   5   0   0   50
5   6   8   8   6   8   8  200
6   7  12  12   7  12   0  242
7   8  13  13   8  13  13  466
8   0  15   0   9  15  15  450
9  10   0   0  10   0   0  200
```

**This code gives an error : TypeError: ('calcMoe() takes exactly 17 arguments (5 given)', u'occurred at index 0')**

```
kwds = {'e1': 'C', 'm1': 'F', 'e2': 'B', 'm2': 'A'}
df['G'] = df.apply(calcMoe, axis=1, **kwds)
```

**One solution would be create a column 'z' with all zero values and pass the e3, e4, m4, m5 as z zero value columns.**

```
df['z']=0
kwds = {'e1': 'C', 'm1': 'F', 'e2': 'B', 'm2': 'A', 'e3':'z', 'm3':'z', 'e4':'z', 'm4':'z'}
df['G'] = df.apply(calcMoe, axis=1, **kwds)
```

This code works but in my case I have to pass several different pairs of the arguments (e,m).

Is there a better solution than creating a column 'z' with zero values? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add default parameter and check for the condition in your calcMoe method i.e

```
def calcMoe(df, e1=None, m1=None, e2=None, m2=None, e3=None, m3=None, e4=None, m4=None):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if  e1 != None:
        if df[e1] == 0:
            x = max(x, df[m1])
        else:
            y = y + df[m1] ** 2      
    if e2 != None:
        if df[e2] == 0: 
            x = max(x, df[m2])
        else:
            y = y + df[m2] ** 2
    if e3 != None :
        if df[e3] == 0 :
            x = max(x, df[m3])
        else:
            y = y + df[m3] ** 2
    if e4 != None :
        if df[e4] == 0 :
            x = max(x, df[m4])
        else:
            y = y + df[m4] ** 2
    return(x ** 2 + y)
```

Then **kwargs work fine.